# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{1+x^n}}{x^n}$ in the case $x<0$ and an analogous problem with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2+x^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{1+x^n}}{x^n}.$$

My first question is: for what values of $x$ is this series possible? I can only say that it is not defined for $x = 0$, but are there other values of $x$ for which the function is not defined?
Second: I've found out that for $x>1$ the series converges, and it diverges if $x=1$ and for $0<x<1$. However I'm confused when it comes to the case $x<0$, which I think I should further divide in $-1<x<0$, $-\infty<x<-1$? What should I do?

I have a problem that seems analogous with 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2+x^n}.$$ For which $x$ is it defined? And how do I study its convergence?

Comment: If $x\lt -1$ then after a while we are trying to find the square root of a negative number, no good. At $x=-1$ you can compute, see that we do not have convergence. And for $-1\lt x\lt 0$ it is even worse, the terms blow up in absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $|x|\geq 1$, your second series does not even have a vanishing term, so in this case the series does not converge. For $0<x<1$, you have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2+x^n}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2}=\frac{2}{1-x}.
$$ 
On the other hand, for $-1<x<0$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2+x^n}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^n}{1}=\frac{1}{1-|x|}.$$

Comment: In this case, you've said that the series does not converge. How do I know if it diverges or is indeterminate (see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291422/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-non-convergent-series-is-indeterminate-or-divergent#1291422)?

Comment: A consequence that you can derivate from the convergence of a series $\sum a_n$ is that the term $a_n$ tends to zero. Therefore, if this condition is not satisfied, the series cannot converge.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm differentiating between diverging to infinity and being indeterminate (oscillating).

Comment: Well, normally you have to study the general term of the series. In this concrete case, when $|x|> 1$, we have that $\frac{x^n}{2+x^n}\to 1$, so your series would "sum" to $+\infty$. For $x=1$, the term is constantly $1/3$, so it would also sum to infinity, and for $x=-1$ the general term will oscillate.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Is it true that if $a_n \to l \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm
\infty\}$ then the series $\sum a_n$ diverge and if $\lim_n a_n$ doesn't exist then the series is indeterminate?

Comment: Maybe you can prove that (assuming $l\neq 0$), or think of a counterexample for that statement, which at this moment I haven't found yet, but divergent means not convergent, so probably you shouldn't worry about that, if you are not asked for it explicitly.

Comment: The thing is that I'm asked to make the difference between divergent to infinity and oscillating in every exercise.