# How can I find out if a non-convergent series is "indeterminate" (that is, "oscillating") or "divergent"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

***Definitions*:**

> Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$, define $$s_n= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j.$$ The
>   sequence $\{s_n\}$ is called the series of partial sums of $\{a_n\}$.
>   A series is *convergent* if $\{s_n\}$ has finite limit; *devergent* if
>   $\{s_n\}$ has an infinite limit; and *indeterminate* if $\{s_n\}$ has
>   no limit.

***Known facts*:**

We have some criteria to determine convergence or divergence of a series if $\{s_n\}$ are all positive (or all negative) for $n$ greater than a certain index $n_0$ (ratio, root, integral tests, etc) or if $\{s_n\}$ has alterning signs (Liebnitz test).

***Problems and questions*:**

> Suppose that a series $ \sum a$ has not all non-negative (or non-positive) terms. Suppose also that we know (for example, by seeing that $a_n \to l \neq 0$) that it is *not-convergent*; what are some strategies to deduce if the series is *divergent* or *indeterminate*?
>
> > In particular, is it true that if $a_n \to l \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm
> > \infty\}$ then the series diverge and if $\lim_n a_n$ doesn't exist
> >     then the series is indeterminate? *Why?*

Comment: If $a_n\to l\neq 0$ then it is divergent; $s_n$ either converges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, depending on the sign of $l$.

Comment: Why is a simple $\epsilon-N$ proof, too long for a comment. You didn't ask "why" in the question above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But don't we know that your statement is true for sure only if the series has all positive (or negative) terms?

Comment: If $a_n\to \ell\neq 0$, then all but finitely many $a_n$ are of the same sign as $\ell$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So you're saing that a generic series (without other assumptions) is actually indeterminate iff the limit of $a_n$ doesn't exist?

Comment: I didn't say that, no. A key to learning math is learning to read precise statements and not to jump to conclusions. What did I actually say? Where did I say "iff"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Then, I'm confused: would you mind writing up and expanding your comments in an answer? And, please, could you also recommend me a book where these details are explained?

Comment: There is a reason I am choosing to write comments.  Sorry.

Comment: This terminology is not universal.  Some use "divergent" to mean simply not convergent.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's why I've added all the definitions.

Comment: Bored now. On to another question. Helping people is fun if they are making an effort, @math-fun, not when they are begging for you to give *more*.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, I've made an effort before asking the question and I'm still making an effort right now.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat broad, but here's a partial answer: If the terms don't approach $0$ and they are all non-negative, then the series diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: I knew that: as I have specified in the question ("suppose a series does not belong to these groups"), I'm interested in the case when the series doesn't have all non-negative (or all non-positive) terms. Thank you anyway :).

Comment: Is it true that if $a_n \to l \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm
\infty\}$ then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges and if $\lim_n a_n$ doesn't exist
then the series is indeterminate?